# An unexpected error happened during phase Publishing of job

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to use the ForgeApp with Revit. For the same I am trying to execute the workitem from Postman. During the execution I am getting below error.

`An unexpected error happened during phase Publishing of job.`

The parts of the actual report (after removing some of the sensitive info) is as follows:

```
[10/15/2020 05:45:24] Finished running.  Process will return: Success
[10/15/2020 05:45:24] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[10/15/2020 05:45:25] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[10/15/2020 05:45:25] End script phase.
[10/15/2020 05:45:25] Start upload phase.
[10/15/2020 05:45:25] Error: Non-optional output [result.json] is missing.
[10/15/2020 05:45:25] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Publishing of job.
[10/15/2020 05:45:25] Job finished with result FailedMissingOutput
[10/15/2020 05:45:25] Job Status:
```

From the error it is clear that the Plugin has failed in processing but it gives give much idea as to why it has failed . After receiving this error, I tried to debug locally by following https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-debug-revit-plugin-locally

But during debugging it is failing with below error while Executing the Plugin itself. It executes the `Onstartup` without any issues but after that it is not going in `HandleDesignAutomationReadyEvent`.

`Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' : 'The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0xdb9b8a8d, on thread 0x3784*`

So I am not sure what to ahead to resolve this. If I can get this working somehow in the Local with Debugger or through Postman then it would help.

Comment: An update from my side -   I have repeated the configuration from Local Debugging from scratch and now at least able to run it without any problems... The problems with Postman connecting to Forge are still continuing though and not getting any headway in that area..

Answer (score 1):

Further update - I have now found the root cause. Even though it was complaining about the missing output file leading me to believe the code was not running properly, the actual root cause was that it was not finding the model from the inputFile parameter. This became clear once I tried putting Console.Write  in the Plugin code and then debugging became easy. I wasn't sure Console would be printed in the output at first and hence turned the debug logs off at first . But as I didn't have any other means to have the verbose logging , I put in lots of Console write and now got to know the root cause.  Thanks